# Magento customer.xml labels

Tags: html, xml, magento, label

I am editing my customer.xml file in Magento. My aim is that I want to style My Account and My Cart etc so that the first word is normal font weight and the second word is bold, I obviously know how to style this but cant get it to work. I have tried using span and strong and it does nothing but return 'Array' instead of My Account for example.

[image: example of what I am trying to achieve]

The code in question in the xml file is like this:

```
<label>My Account</label>
<label>My <strong>Account</strong></label>
<label>My <span>Account</span></label>
```

either of these last two return "ARRAY"

Anyone have any ideas how to overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding text inside CDATA tags to force the text to be treated as character data.

```
<label><![CDATA[My <strong>Account</strong>]]></label>
```

I'm not sure how this will work in Magento though.

You could try and modify the links.phtml template to do what you need though.

template/page/html/top.links.phtml